# Mongoose behaviour around Min and Max with Number

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a Mongoose scheme like so...

`lightbox_opacity:{type:Number, min:0, max:1}`

I have 2 issues...

1. When I try to insert a string "abc", it quietly ignores this fields insertion. Rest of the fields in the Schema get inserted successfully. I was under the impression that it will throw an exception. Is it possible to do that?
2. If I try to insert 5, it simply allows it and it appears that min & max didn't come into play at all.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [validation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) could help you. One example as below.

```
var min = [0, 'The value of path `{PATH}` ({VALUE}) is beneath the limit ({MIN}).'];
var max = [1, 'The value of path `{PATH}` ({VALUE}) exceeds the limit ({MAX}).'];
var numberschema = new mongoose.Schema({
    n: {type: Number, min: min, max: max}
 });

var numberschema = mongoose.model('number', numberschema, 'number');

var insertDocuments = function(db) { 
    var a = new numberschema({
        n: 5
    });

    console.log(a);       

    a.validate(function(err) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
    });
    a.save(function (err, ack) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Mongoose save error : ' + err);
        } else { 
            console.log('Mongoose save successfully...'); 
        }
    }); 
};
```

When try to insert `5`, error as below

```
{ [ValidationError: Validation failed]
  message: 'Validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError',
  errors:
   { n:
      { [ValidatorError: The value of path `n` (5) exceeds the limit (1).]
        message: 'The value of path `n` (5) exceeds the limit (1).',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        path: 'n',
        type: 'max',
        value: 5 } } }
Mongoose save error : ValidationError: The value of path `n` (5) exceeds the lim
it (1).
```

When try to insert `abc`, error as below

```
Mongoose save error : CastError: Cast to number failed for value "abc" at path "
n"
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out shortly. So, is this the recommended method? As I said, I was under the assumption that this should just work. Please correct me if I am wrong. I am relatively new to Mongoose.

Comment: @RahulSoni, yes, `Validation` is recommended method, more details please refer to the link in my answer.