# Mongoose $inc with maximum value

Tags: node.js, mongoose, model, increment

So I'm currently trying to perform this operation

```
return this.model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $push: { certifiedBy: certifier } }, { $inc: {score: 1}}, { new: true })
```

The issue here is that `score` will grow without limit, I would like to prevent this and make it so when this is happening it cannot increment if `score <= 5` but still add `certifier` into my `certifiedBy` array.

Can it be done with mongoose directly or do I have to get the object first check if it over 5 and call a different query in that case ?

Thanks

Comment: You can limit your field using max in schema... see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34892143/mongoose-behaviour-around-min-and-max-with-number

Comment: answer posted below, please approve answer if your like my efforts

Comment: I commented your answer, can you make sure it's gonna work in the situation I said ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the $inc behaviour but you can do a checkpoint to stop it before 5

```
return this.model.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: id,
    score: {
        $lte: 5
    }
}, {
        $push: { certifiedBy: certifier },
        $inc: { score: 1 }
    },
    {
        new: true
    })
```

Comment: If i'm understanding well, this will not push in `certifiedBy`, what I want is `certifiedBy` to still be updated (add the new certifier inside) but not increment score.

I might be wrong when it comes to the understanding of your code

Comment: in this case it is not possible

Comment: you have to update certificate separately and increment functionality seperately